# Position of Text in SwiftUI keeps changing when its text is updated

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am using Text to create a floating label for TextField but when user the value of Text is updated , it changes its position vertically and due to which other elements gets disturbed too.
Please have a look at the package.

https://github.com/maxakash/FloatingLabelTextField

Comment: Can you add the part of the code that you want people to look at?

Comment: i have added the link for the package . It contains both the code as well as gif showing the problem